Webpack Duplicate Image File Issue and 404 Error with React App
I am working on a React project with Webpack to bundle my assets. My issue is that Webpack is creating duplicate image files in the dist/images directory, and my application is also encountering a 404 error for one of the images.
Webpack creates two image files in dist/images: un_logo.png and un_logo.[hash].png.
The application throws a 404 error for the image when trying to load it:
Here's my project structure:
bash
/project
  /src
    /images
      un_logo.png
    index.js
    style.css
  /dist
    /images
      un_logo.png
      un_logo.[hash].png
  webpack.config.js

Webpack Configuration:
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name].[hash][ext][query]',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: 'src/images', to: 'images' }],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
};

Sample of my react code :
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import unLogo from './images/un_logo.png'; // Correctly importing the image

const App = () => {
  // State and handlers...

  return (
  
            <img src={unLogo} alt="UN Logo" className="logo" />
            <div className="name">
              <span className="first-name">{formData.firstName.toLowerCase()}</span>
              <span className="last-name">{formData.lastName.toUpperCase()}</span>
            </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));

What I Tried:
Ensured the image path is correct in the React component.
Checked Webpack configuration for any misconfigurations related to image handling.
Verified that the image exists in the source directory (src/images).

Question:
How can I prevent Webpack from creating duplicate image files and resolve the 404 error for the image in my React application?
